# Como posso evitar que a macro de um botão de formulário de uma planilha anterior seja copiada junto aos dados para a planilha atual?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Eu fiz um formulário de cadastro de funcionarios bem básico (teste mesmo, nada oficial) usando código vba em um arquivo que chamei de Planilha Teste VBA 1. Até aí tudo certo, consegui de boa. Daí eu adicionei na própria planilha do excel o botão de formulário para a pessoa apertar, o formulário ser gerado, tudo certinho. Até aí td ok. Sendo que dps me pediram para criar um outro arquivo excel externo a esse, que eu chamei de Pasta teste para importar dados de outra planilha. Foi complicado mas consegui oq queriam, preenchi o codigo VBA de modo que ele copie os dados da Planilha Teste VBA 1. Porém, eu só quero que copie os dados. Mas ele acaba copiando o botão de formulário também. E eu já tentei de td para evitar que esse botão de formulário da planilha Teste VBA 1 seja copiado, mas ainda não consegui.

No caso a linha de código VBA que estou usando é a seguinte:

**Sub ImportarDados()
Dim wb As Workbook 'declara uma variável para o arquivo que será aberto
Dim planilhaAtual As Worksheet 'declara uma variável para a planilha atual
Dim planilhaDados As Worksheet 'declara uma variável para a planilha de origem (dados)
Dim caminhoArquivo As String 'declara uma variável para o caminho do arquivo
Dim arquivoSelecionado As Variant 'declara uma variável para armazenar o nome do arquivo selecionado

```
'Mostra uma janela para que o usuário selecione o arquivo externo
arquivoSelecionado = Application.GetOpenFilename("Arquivos do Excel (.xlsx;.xlsm),.xlsx;.xlsm")

'Se o usuário selecionar um arquivo, carrega o caminho do arquivo no módulo VBA
If arquivoSelecionado <> False Then 'verifica se o usuário selecionou um arquivo
    caminhoArquivo = arquivoSelecionado 'armazena o caminho do arquivo selecionado
    
    'Abre o arquivo selecionado
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(caminhoArquivo)

    'Defina a planilha atual (onde o código VBA está sendo executado)
    Set planilhaAtual = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'define a planilha atual como a ativa

    'Extrai o nome da planilha de origem
    Set planilhaDados = wb.Worksheets(1) 'Assumindo que a planilha de origem é a primeira na lista
    Dim nomePlanilha As String 'declara uma variável para armazenar o nome da planilha de origem
    nomePlanilha = planilhaDados.Name 'armazena o nome da planilha de origem
    
    'Extrai o intervalo de dados da planilha de origem
    Dim intervaloDados As Range 'declara uma variável para o intervalo de dados
    Set intervaloDados = planilhaDados.Range("A1:BB200") 'Altere o intervalo conforme necessário
    
   For Each obj In planilhaDados.Shapes 'percorre cada objeto (forma) na planilha de origem
If obj.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then 'verifica se é um botão de comando
    If Not obj.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CADASTRAR" Then 'verifica se o botão não é o botão da macro original
        obj.Delete 'exclui o botão de comando
    End If
Else
    obj.Copy 'copia os outros objetos
    planilhaAtual.Paste 'cola os outros objetos na planilha atual
End If
```

Next obj

```
    intervaloDados.Copy planilhaAtual.Range("A1") 'copia o intervalo de dados para a planilha atual

    'Feche o arquivo que você importou os dados
    wb.Close False 'fecha o arquivo sem salvar
    
    'Mostra uma mensagem informando o nome da planilha de origem e o caminho do arquivo
    MsgBox "Os dados foram importados da planilha " & nomePlanilha & " no arquivo " & caminhoArquivo & "."

End If
```

End Sub**

Só sei que já alterei consideravelmente essa parte daqui várias vezes ( **For Each obj In planilhaDados.Shapes 'percorre cada objeto (forma) na planilha de origem
If obj.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then 'verifica se é um botão de comando
If Not obj.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CADASTRAR" Then 'verifica se o botão não é o botão da macro original
obj.Delete 'exclui o botão de comando
End If
Else
obj.Copy 'copia os outros objetos
planilhaAtual.Paste 'cola os outros objetos na planilha atual
End If
Next obj**
) que nem sei mais qual foi a última q tentei, mas já fiz diversas tentativas e ainda não achei a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar a cópia do botão de formulário presente na planilha de origem, você pode verificar se o objeto é um botão de formulário e, se for, ignorá-lo durante o loop. Para fazer isso, você pode adicionar uma nova condição dentro do loop For Each:

```
For Each obj In planilhaDados.Shapes
    If obj.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
        ' Verifica se é um botão de formulário
        If obj.OLEFormat.Object.progID = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then
            ' Ignora o botão de formulário
        ElseIf Not obj.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "CADASTRAR" Then
            ' Copia os outros objetos
            obj.Copy
            planilhaAtual.Paste
        End If
    Else
        ' Copia os outros objetos
        obj.Copy
        planilhaAtual.Paste
    End If
Next obj
```

Observe que adicionamos um novo If para verificar se o objeto é um botão de formulário e, em seguida, outro If para ignorá-lo. Você também pode adicionar outras condições conforme necessário, por exemplo, se houver outros objetos que você queira excluir ou incluir. Espero que isso ajude!